# How to fire an event after n seconds of maintained click? - jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure I am not the first looking for this, but I did not find any solution to my problem..

I am looking for a way to fire an event after and only after a 3 seconds maintained click.
I tried with javascript setInterval() function with mouseup/mousedown Jquery events but it did't work.

Someone has an idea ?

I have a div, I keep the mouse button down for 3 seconds, and something will be fired.
3 seconds timer must be reinitialized every time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call `setTimeout()` to perform your action after 3000 milliseconds, storing the identifier from `setTimeout()` into a variable scoped above the function.  On the element's `mouseup()`, clear the timeout if it exists via `clearTimeout()`.

```
var divMouseDown;
$('#div-id').mousedown(function() {
  divMouseDown = setTimeout(function() {
     // Do timeout action...
  }, 3000);
});
$('#div-id').mouseup(function() {
  if (divMouseDown) {
    clearTimeout(divMouseDown);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow, My code was the same, but I placed the "do timeout action" in mouseup event.. Thank you!

Comment: Just a minor performance tidbit: you can chain the event handlers to avoid calling `$('#div-id')` twice. `});
$('#div-id').mouseup(function() {` => `}).mouseup(function() {`

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard So this code actually works like you expect? Great.

Comment: @BenLee I tend not to think very jQuery-mindedly in that way. Actually I changed my initial code from straight JS to use jQuery instead.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard, hah, I originally made the exact same mistake as you in the answer I posted (I fixed it after a commenter pointed it out to me).

Comment: @BenLee ahah I did't see it !

Answer (score 1):

On mouse down, set a timeout for 3 seconds in the future.

On mouse up, clear the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `mouseup`/`mousedown` events and `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` *is* the way to do it:

```
var timer = null;

$(selector).on('mousedown', function(ev) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timer = null;

        /* Do something */
    }, 3000);
}.on('mouseup', function(ev) {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: The answer does not require a mouseup event to ever be triggered. This is the person holding the mouse down.

Comment: seems that you should swap `mouseup` and `mousedown` keyword

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div').on('mousedown', function(){
    mousetimer.down();
}).on('mouseup', function(){
    mousetimer.cancel();
});

var mousetimer = {
    timer: null,
    timing: false,
    down: function(){
        if(!timing)
        {
            mousetimer.timing = true;
            mousetimer.timer = setTimeout(function(){
                mousetimer.trigger();
            }, 3000);
        }
    },
    trigger: function(){
        alert('do something');
        mousetimer.cancel();
    },
    cancel: function(){
        mousetimer.timing = false;
        clearTimeout(mousetimer.timer);
    }
};
```

Comment: It is, I just knew this would receive many answers so I gave an elaborate example so the functions could also be called outside of a listener, should you ever want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout of 3000ms.

Set the timeout on the mouse down event, clear it on the mouse up event.

http://jsfiddle.net/kHMWX/