# How To Call A Function After 'X' seconds Of onmousedown event

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I want to call a Function after a user hold the button for 'x' seconds. Please help.

Comment: No attempt/effort/research shown.

Comment: Better do some search & try out writing some by yourself before posting a question. Anyway, you can try this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371280/how-to-fire-an-event-after-n-seconds-of-maintained-click-jquery-javascript

Comment: Google is your best guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call setTimeout() to perform your action after 3000 milliseconds, storing the identifier from setTimeout() into a variable scoped above the function. On the element's mouseup(), clear the timeout if it exists via clearTimeout().

```
var divMouseDown;
$('#div-id').mousedown(function() {
divMouseDown = setTimeout(function() {
 // Do timeout action...
}, 3000);
});
$('#div-id').mouseup(function() {
if (divMouseDown) {
 clearTimeout(divMouseDown);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function () {
function someFunction()
{
    alert("do something");
}

var x = 2000; // 2000 miliseconds = 2 seconds
var mousePressed = false;
var timePressed = 0;
var timeHolding = 0;

function check(){
    timeHolding = new Date().getTime() - timePressed;        
    if(timeHolding >= x){
        someFunction();
    }
}    
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {         
    if(!mousePressed){
        mousePressed = true; 
        timePressed = new Date().getTime(); // or Date.now()        
        setTimeout(function(){ check() }, x);
    }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {         
    mousePressed = false;        
    timePressed = new Date().getTime(); 
}, false);
})();
```

Check it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/m4d4c/).

Comment: First version of the answer just execute someFunction 2 seconds after the pressing. This new version only execute the function after 2 seconds holding the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.target').primarydown( function() {
    released = false;
    $(this).primaryup( function() {
      released = true;
    });
    setTimeout( function() {
      if( released ) return;
      else {
         // call required function
      }
     }, 1000 /* timeout */ );
});
```